# Is there a way to disable the warnings "Invalid event handler property `onclick`" of React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm building a webapp with React where I need to display some ads. The problem is as follows:

I need to display these ads inside a React component, I've been give the html code of these ads and they work fine (So far) but they throw a big warning:

```
    index.js:1375 Warning: Invalid event handler property `onclick`. Did you mean `onClick`?
        in a (at ad-display.component.jsx:4)
```

I do know that the reason of the warning is the onclick property that should be onClick instead, however I don't want to mess up with the original HTML code that has been given to me, in case it would affect my client's revenue

The code of the ad is a simple a tag:

```
    <a onclick="setSomething(event, this)" href="http://coollink.com" id="rt_aff_banner_514" border="0" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="https://coolimage/1543860030.png"/></a>
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to disable these warning, cause it's getting very dificult to debug with them.

Also, feel free to scold me if the way I'm doing this is all wrong and I would need to insert this html code in any other way into my React code

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `onClick={(event) => setSomething(event, this)}`

Comment: You're not exactly showing how you're injecting that code. Given that error, I assume you're note using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) which is kind of the only thing you should be using if you want to inject that untrusted HTML code. The other option is to just use proper code, and trust that React will generate perfectly valid HTML off of that (which it will).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is dangerously set inner html:

```
const ads = `<a onclick="setSomething(event, this)" 
   href="http://coollink.com" id="rt_aff_banner_514"
   border="0" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" src="https://coolimage/1543860030.png"/>
   </a>`

<div id="ads" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ads }}></div>
```

Comment: His problem is in `onclick` because there's no such thing in JSX. All he need to do is follow what @Omer said.

Comment: OP clearly stating he can use `onClick` but he's looking for the other way. So, I think it's the way how OP want.

Comment: The reason why he's looking for other way is because of that warning he posted. The reason why he's getting that warning is because he used `onclick` instead of `onClick`.

Comment: Yeah, and OP is aware of that.

Comment: even if he use your solution it will still produce that warning. Things are a bit different in React especially in handling onclick events.

Comment: No. Dangerously setting inner html will parse the html content exactly as per the string of html.

Comment: Thank you  Bhojendra Rauniyar this solution worked, the ads still work (I think xD) or at least they take me to the ad site. And the warning is gone. Sorry it took me some time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

**@HanselDoullery** It's a syntax warning for react. You are binding html event handler `onclick`, it will work as normal event handler but react compiler will give you warning as in react syntax for binding click event is slightly different. Please refer this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

In your case you will write your `click` handler something like this:

```
<a onClick={()=> { setSomething(event, this)}} ...>
....
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a global function you could try this:

```js
<a onClick={(e)=> { window.setSomething(event, this); }} ref="http://coollink.com" id="rt_aff_banner_514" border="0" target="_blank">
....
</a>
```